# reading deleted records in php

Tags: php

I have a code like this where user selects field1 from a list box and click on submit to delete all data for the selected value.

```
$sql = "delete from table where field1 = '$parameter' ;
mssql_query ($sql);
```

On successful delete i.e. after submit, I want to display text something like "Deleted 153 records from table"

How it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mssql_rows_affected()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-rows-affected.php) :

```
$sql = "delete from table where field1 = '$parameter' "; //added closing quotes
mssql_query ($sql);
echo "Deleted " . mssql_rows_affected($database_link) . " records from table."; //where `$database_link` is the variable that contains the `mssql_connect` statement
```

Comment: I get error " Call to undefined function mssql_affected_rows()"

Comment: thanks i corrected it but still I get error `mssql_rows_affected(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in file.php on line ..`

Comment: The `$database_link` should contain the mssql connection link as said in the manual, are you sure that this it the case?

Comment: oh yes...now it's working...but by default it displays message "deleted 0 records" ...can I hide this line? I want to display this only after submit.

Comment: You can do something like: `if(form_submitted) { "Deleted " . mssql_rows_affected($database_link) . " records from table."; }` but I would have to see your source code for a more detailed solution.

Answer (score 1):

With a call to [mssql_rows_affected](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-rows-affected.php):

```
$sql = "delete from table where field1 = '$parameter'";
mssql_query ($sql);

echo 'Deleted ' . mssql_rows_affected($link) . ' row(s)';
```

Where `$link` is your database connection.

Comment: to use your code, i don't understand where to place the line mssql_query `('Truncate Table...)`..shall I replace it with my query?

Comment: Please don't! That's an example line from their code. You should replace that line with your own SQL - you just need to run the `mssql_rows_affected()` line. I'll update the answer.